# how to sync Xcode with VS code

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I am trying to sync VS Code and Xcode so changes that I make in Xcode can be updated to my VS code project.

[The option I'm trying to use, but VS code won't allow me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkRYl.png)

Comment: You have an IMPOSSIBLE combination of TAGS: If you have `.xaml` files, then it is `Xamarin.Forms` and is `cross-platform UI` - CANNOT open in `xcode`. If you have `.storyboard` and `.nib` files, then it is `Xamarin.iOS` - open in xcode to edit those files. NOT CROSS-PLATFORM! In that case, sorry, I don't know why it won't let you sync. (`.cs` files exist in both of those variants of xamarin.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve   How do you suggest I go about this? Do I just make my app from scratch on Xcode or is their a way to make the iOS app bundle on my windows PC using Xamarin?

Comment: I can do the same steps and then sync as Steve pointed out. I don't think there's a way that can make the iOS app bundle on the windows PC using Xamarin, if there's one, please keep me informed! Thanks!